# Recreate OOTB Timer Job

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, timer-jobs

Just accidentally deleted an out-of-the-box timer job in SharePoint Foundation 2010, the "`Change Log`" Timer Job, using PowerShell (`SPJobDefinition.Delete()`) in a farm with only one server.

How can I recreate/bring it back? Tried running SharePoint Configuration Wizard to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to restore the OOTB, you need to perform the below steps.

- Firstly, run the Configuration Wizard to reprovision the Farm-scoped
  Timer Jobs.
- Then, for each Web Application you have, run the following
  PowerShell:

  ```
  $w = Get-SPWebApplication https://mywebapplication
  $w.EnsureDefaultJobs()
  ```

  This will recreate the default timer jobs (stuff like Alerts, site cleanup, etc.)

http://omicron-llama.co.uk/2015/03/27/accidentally-deleted-all-timer-jobs-fear-not/